# Create Relationship between Account Nodes based on Listings Nodes sharing same Phone Number

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 2 Account Nodes, and several listing nodes, as seen below. The Match statement results in 2 Accounts being show with a relationship to each Listing thats associated to that account.

What im wanting to do is create a relationship between the two Accounts based on at least 1 of there listings each sharing the same phone number.

If possible im wanting to see the relationship between the two account nodes drawn and a relationship between the two listings so long as the listings are from different Account.

```
MERGE (:Account {account_id:11})
MERGE (:Listing {account_id:11, listing_id:1001, phone:99468320, author:'Paul'})

MERGE (:Account {account_id:12})
MERGE (:Listing {account_id:12, listing_id:1002, phone:97412521, author:'Sam'})
MERGE (:Listing {account_id:12, listing_id:1003, phone:97412521, author:'Sam'})
MERGE (:Listing {account_id:12, listing_id:1004, phone:99468320, author:'Sam'})
MERGE (:Listing {account_id:12, listing_id:1004, phone:0, author:'Same'})


MATCH (a:Account),(l:Listing)
WHERE a.account_id = l.account_id
CREATE (a)-[:LISTING]->(l)
RETURN a,l;
```

For the latter i did try the following but it went a bit crazy as it linked every listing to each other that had the same number appose to only doing so if the account_id was different.

```
match (p1:Listing)
with p1
match (p2:Listing)
where p2.phone = p1.phone and p1 <> p2
merge(p1)-[r:SHARED_PHONE]-(p2)
RETURN p1, p2
```

Comment: Why don't you just replace `p1 <> p2` with `p1.account_id <> p2.account_id`? By definition, if the account id's don't match, they are not the same node. (or `NOT p1.account_id = p2.account_id` if you want it to be a bit more readable) Also, this would create 2 relationships, one for each direction. Are you sure you don't want to just break the phone numbers out to their own node to make your following Cyphers easier?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should carefully consider if you really need the `SHARED_PHONE` relationships, as you will have to update the relationships every time a phone number is added, removed, or changed. That could complicate a lot of your queries and make your DB unnecessarily slower. Also, you could end up with a lot of `SHARED_PHONE` relationships (that you may not really need). Instead of creating the relationships, you could consider incorporating into the relevant queries the discovery of the nodes with the same phone numbers.

However, if you decide that you really need that relationship, here is one way to do what you want:

[UPDATED]

```
MATCH (n: Listing)
WITH n.phone AS phone, COLLECT(n) AS ns
FOREACH(i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(ns)-2) |
  FOREACH(x IN [ns[i]] |
    FOREACH(y IN [z IN ns[i+1..] WHERE x.account_id <> z.account_id] |
      MERGE (x)-[:SHARED_PHONE]-(y) 
    )))
```

The `WITH` clause collects all the (unique) `Listing` nodes that share the same `phone`, and the nested `FOREACH` clauses execute the minimum number of `MERGE`s needed to ensure that all the appropriate nodes are connected by a `SHARED_PHONE` relationship (in either direction). The innermost `FOREACH` also ensures that the nodes to be connected do not have the same `account_id`.

Comment: The data would not be changed after it has been created, the purpose for this query is to establish multipule account usage,

Comment: That query doesn't seem to work, as its creating relationships between the listings under the same account, where as i only wanted them if two accounts share the same phone number.

Comment: This seems way over complicated for the task of finding listing pairs that have the same phone but different account_id... What are all the FOREACH for? And why do that over `where p2.phone = p1.phone and p1.account_id <> p2.account_id`?